does $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)\exp(g_i(x))$, $g_i(x)-g_j(x) \neq \text{constant}, (i \neq j)$ has elementary primitive function?
Let $f(x), g(x) \in \mathbb{C}(x)$ and $g(x) \neq \text{constant}$, if $g_i(x)-g_j(x) \neq \text{constant}, (i \neq j)$, does $\sum_{i=1}^{n}f_i(x)\exp(g_i(x))$ has elementary primitive function?
I know Liouville's theorem, and use that can do some special case, like $\frac{\sin x}{x} = \frac{e^z}{2z}-\frac{e^{-z}}{2z}, (z=ix)$ has no elementary primitive function. how about the general case please?
Clearly, when $f_k(x)\exp(g_k(x))$ has elementary primitive function for every $k$, it has elementary primitive function. if $\exists k$ such that $f_k(x)\exp(g_k(x))$ has no elementary primitive function, is it same?

$e^x$ has an elementary primitive function but $e^{x^2}$ doesn't, so we can't say much in general.

@Tuvasbien as that, $e^x+e^{x^2}$ has no elementary primitive function, because one term of the sum has no. general, $n-$ term of sum still like that?

Perhaps to do proofs like this, you must first understand the proof of Liouville's theorem.
